# How to get my data accepted in the Linked Open Data Cloud Diagram?

Tags: linked-data

The [Linked Open Data Cloud Diagram](http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/lodcloud/2014/) is a cool diagram showing about 570 datasets:

[image: Linked Open Data Cloud Diagram]

What are the steps to get my dataset into the next version of this diagram?

And more importantly, what are the technical/legal requirements for my dataset?

Also, what can I do to maximize the chances of my dataset getting accepted into this diagram? (For instance, I guess a dataset which is very small, extremely specialized, and in Japanese, would have lower chances than a large famous well-linked dataset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

essentially you need to:

1. validate your dataset with ckan lod validator
2. publish dataset
3. add it to ckan "so that it appears in the next version of the lod cloud diagram"

Reference: http://datahub.io/group/about/lodcloud